# ember-cli migration: global app module import

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm having some slight ember-cli migration difficulties with the global application variable.

In `project/app/app.js` I define App as:

```
var App;
Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;
App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver: Resolver
});
```

Then in a separate controller, `project/app/controllers/auth.js`, I attempt to access `App` using the following statement:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import App from '../app.js';
```

This results in an extremely odd error from when running the application.  I receive the following error from the Chrome inspector (or Firebug):

```
Uncaught Error:  Could not find module 'project/app.js' imported 
from 'project/controllers/auth'
```

At first glance this appears to be a path error in my import statement.  However, efforts to fix the path have proven useless.  Then I also noticed that the imported portion of the error was not including the correct path either!  It should read `project/app/controllers/auth` but instead reads `project/controllers/auth`.  I'm quite confused as to what's happening here.

Please let me know if I can provide more details at all, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the module path contains the `.js` extension. Change the path to just `'../app'` and it will work just fine.